# Indesign script to automate order list by last name

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript, script, grep

Every month I have to order a long list of names alphabetically by last name.
**Is there a way to do this all in one single script?**

**This is what I am currently doing:**
Use a GREP to place the last names before the first names, sort the list using the SortParagraphs VBScript, then use another GREP to place the last names after the first names.

**Step 1:**
Use a GREP to place the last names before the first names using these settings.
Find what: `^(.+?) (.+)`
Change to: `$2@$1`

**Step 2:**
Sort the list using: *Scripts>Application>Samples>VBScript>SortParagraphs*
*(note - i am using the VBScript because the JS script makes my file crash every time)*

**Step 3:**
Use another GREP to place the last names after the first names using these settings.
Find what: `^(.+)@(.+)`
Change to: `$2 $1`

Comment: have you tried indesign's data merge features? You can presort a csv/data file prior to bringing it in. Or simply export the names to a text file and paste it.

Comment: Why not do the ordering in Excel, before importing the data into INDD ?